# Liferay 7 JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil doesn't return articleDisplay content

Tags: templates, liferay, osgi, freemarker

I'm using Liferay 7 GA5, and I'm developing OSGI modules.
I wrote my web contents using a working freemarker template starting with the following code:

```
<#assign serviceContext = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal"].getServiceContext()>
<#assign themeDisplay = serviceContext.getThemeDisplay() />
```

Now I need to access programmatically the web content, but if I access from a portlet:

```
JournalArticleDisplay articleDisplay = 
                JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticleDisplay(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), articleId, null, themeDisplay.getLanguageId(), themeDisplay);

        String title = articleDisplay.getTitle();
        String content = articleDisplay.getContent();
     ...
```

the content string contains this error:

```
 <div class="journal-template-error">
  <span class="alert alert-error">
     Si è verificato un errore nell'elaborarazione del modello.    </span>

 <pre>No error description was specified for this error; low-level message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal cannot be found by com.liferay.portal.template.freemarker_2.0.27

----
FTL stack trace (&quot;~&quot; means nesting-related):
- Failed at: #assign serviceContext = staticUtil[&quot;...  [in template &quot;10135#10168#MODELLOXXX&quot; at line 1, column 1]
----</pre>
```

This means that com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal is not available to freemarker in this context: how is it possible to make it available. Another solution is to work around by applying another template to the web content on the fly: is it possible?